# Does NIO Connector & Async servlet & Async IO work better under high concurrency

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, tomcat7, httpclient

The situation looks like these:

1. There are some minutes in a week, it can have 1M req/s in each of these minutes.
2. We have about 100 instances to hold the requests.
3. Each instance has a spring dispatcher servlet to handle the request, the logic is very simple, translate the requests and send them to other services. Those service will take about 1s avg to process the translated requests. So, these instances running with low CPU currently.
4. We are using apr connector with 8192 maxConnection, 300 accept count and sync servlet, sync httpclient to call other services.

Now, we are suffering a heavy timeout. So, we have three opyions:

- NIO connector
- Async servlet(using DeferedResult)
- Async IO(I.e. AsyncHttpClient). Set deferred result after http request complete

Can these options work in our situation? Or, any better idea?

Comment: Async servlets are good if you have some long-running requests that primarily wait for something. Using Read?Write listeners in async context might be a good  idea in case of slow clients.

Comment: @SvetlinZarev what is the definition of slow clients? Can a smartphone application be considered as a slow client if its using 3G or 2G network?

Comment: a slow client is a client that does read or write with slow speed. For instance reading with 1kb/sec while all others are reading with 1mb/sec. There are no concrete thresholds though. The issue with slow clients is that they consume container threads (for a  prolonged time)  while doing almost nothing at the same time. In that case async IO (read/write listeners) wpould help to reduce the number of consumed container threads.